# 3Sum like algorithm to find equations

Tags: c

[image]

```
a+b+c+d+e = e+d+f+g+h = h+g+k+b+a
```

each variable [a..k] is between [1-9] and each variable has to get ***unique number.***

every number between 1-9 **has to be used**.

**all** posibilites have to be found. (Language is C)

above equations should be solved as instructed. I could not even start thinking about some sort of algorithm to find solution. If someone help/guide me to solution, I'll appeciate it. It is not a homework, I was just trying to challenge myself but here I am with not even a code snippet.. I do not wan't full code or long explanations. I just want some guide or suggestions to find solution/s.

EDIT: I have brute force algorithm that find solutions. I want to do it with better way.

Comment: '. I could not even start thinking about some sort of algorithm to find solution.' - Really? Not even brute force? ...

Comment: If all solutions have to be found, I don't think there's any other option but to check all possible permutations.

Comment: @Transcendental I did it with brute force

Comment: Have tried to find a pattern in the possible solutions?

Comment: @pytheos yes I have a pattern that find all possible solutions. code works but it has too much if statements.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. When you look at the possible combinations (the solution), can you spot any pattern (i.e. e can only be odd)?

Comment: @pytheos oh sorry about that, I did not see any pattern. I just hard coded all the combinations.

Comment: @kaanyılmaz Then maybe there is no way to do it smarter ;-)

Comment: @pytheos but it seems like 3sum algorithm..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109558/discussion-between-pytheos-and-kaan-yilmaz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since brute force is always an option you could try the following:

1. Write a function `int check(int foo[])` that takes an array of integers and checks whether your formula holds. `foo[0]` holds the value for a, `foo[1]` holds the value for b, etc.
2. Generate all possible array combinations and print those combinations for which `int check(int foo[])` holds.

EDIT: The question has been "solved" in the chat afterwards.

The following code generates all possible array combinations via recursion and checks whether the formula is satisfied. If this is the case, the counter is incremented. The number of found combinations is 864.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int check();
void rec(int);
void swap(int, int);


int foo[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int match = 0;

int main(void)
{
    rec(-1);
    printf("%d combinations have been found", match);
    return(0);
}

// generate all possible combinations for the array foo
void rec(int fix)
{
    if(fix == 8) { // base case
        if(check() == 1){
            match++;
        }
    } else { // inductive step
        int i;
        for(i = fix + 1; i < 9; i++){
            swap(fix + 1, i);
            rec(fix + 1);
            swap(fix + 1, i); 
        }
    }
}

// swap position i with j in array foo
void swap(int i, int j)
{
    int v = foo[i];
    foo[i] = foo[j];
    foo[j] = v;
}

// check whether the condition holds
int check()
{
    int f1 = foo[0]+foo[1]+foo[2]+foo[3]+foo[4]; // a+b+c+d+e
    int f2 = foo[4]+foo[3]+foo[5]+foo[6]+foo[7]; // e+d+f+g+h
    int f3 = foo[7]+foo[6]+foo[8]+foo[1]+foo[0]; // h+g+k+b+a
    return ((f1 == f2) && (f2 == f3));
}
```